# How to Write Excel VBA Code in VS Code Editor

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio-code

Is it Possible to write and run Excel VBA code in VS code if yes so please tell me how.

And is possible to make window based application in VS Code.

Comment: No. VBA needs it's host application, e.g. Excel, to run. You can, however, write C# or VB.Net code to deal with Excel or Word files.

Comment: Look into twinBASIC

Answer (score 0):

Note that VS code is only an Editor which does not run any code you write there.

It is not possible to run Excel VBA code in anything else than Microsoft Excel.

You can write a stand alone application in any programming language you like and that has a library that supports Microsoft Excel files. But to run VBA you need Excel.

Comment: @PEH  have you taken a look at twinbasic?